# How to use the Term Object from a custom select field in a query

Tags: wp-query, categories, custom-field, taxonomy

I have a WordPress site in which I want to show 2 recent posts from a specific category. I want to use custom fields (via ACF in this case) to allow the site admin to choose/change the category displayed in each area.

Because there will be several instances of this in one page, I have set up a group of taxonomy fields – settings as follows:

- Taxonomy: Category
- Appearance: Select
- Return Value: Term Object

I am implementing these fields as follows:

```
<?php if(have_rows('page_sections')) : while(have_rows('page_sections')) : the_row(); ?>
 
 <?php 
  $cat = get_sub_field('category');
  $cat_id = esc_html( $cat->ID );
  $cat_args = array(
   'cat' => $cat_id,
   'nopaging' => false,
   'posts_per_page' => 2,
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
  );
  $cat_query = new WP_Query( $cat_args );
  if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $cat ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?></a></h3>
  <?php while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post(); ?>
   <!-- Displaying post data here -->
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 <?php else : endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : endif; ?>
```

The category name and link are generated as expected in the `h3` tags on line 14 here, but my issue is that the `cat =>` part of the query makes no difference to the result. Posts are displayed as I expect, but I am getting the 2 most recent posts from ALL categories rather than the specified one.

How do I get the term object from the sub field to filter my query?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you `var_dump( $cat_id);` what do you get?

Comment: just a path to the page template file, with the line number appended: `../homepage.php:63:`. i admit i don't know what i should be expecting to see?

Comment: Well that should be the ID.  That's why your query isn't returning any results. If you extrapolate your `$args` with what's actually there you're getting `'cat' => '.../homepage.php:63:',` and that's not going to work.

Comment: thanks tony – i see what you mean. looking at my code i can't see why i wouldn't be getting the id though, can you? i've tried using ` $cat_id =  $cat->ID` (no `esc_html`) but the result is the same path with `:null` at the end..

Comment: i have it. i needed `$cat_id = $cat->term_id` and not `$cat_id = $cat->ID`, thank you @TonyDjukic for teaching me about the `var_dump` trick and helping me zero in on the root of the issue.

Comment: Awesome news, glad I was able to help.  I now use `var_dump()` every time I generate a dynamic variable, just to make sure I'm getting what I expect.  It's like the most common little thing I write and delete, write and delete, write and delete.  Lol!